# vb.net Stringbuilder to create HTML file

Tags: html, vb.net, stringbuilder

I am using a `StringBuilder` to create a HTML file from my `DataTable`. The file is created but when I open it in the webbrowser I have to scroll all the way down to see the table. In other words there is a big blank page first with nothing at all.

```
Public Function ConvertToHtmlFile(ByVal myTable As DataTable) As String
        Dim myBuilder As New StringBuilder
        If myTable Is Nothing Then
            Throw New System.ArgumentNullException("myTable")
        Else
                
            'Open tags and write the top portion. 
            myBuilder.Append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>")
            myBuilder.Append("<head>")
            myBuilder.Append("<title>")
            myBuilder.Append("Page-")
            myBuilder.Append("CLAS Archive")
            myBuilder.Append("</title>")
            myBuilder.Append("</head>")
            myBuilder.Append("<body>")
            myBuilder.Append("<br /><table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ")
            myBuilder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>")


            myBuilder.Append("<br /><tr align='left' valign='top'>")

            For Each myColumn As DataColumn In myTable.Columns
                myBuilder.Append("<br /><td align='left' valign='top' style='border: solid 1px blue;'>")
                myBuilder.Append(myColumn.ColumnName)
                myBuilder.Append("</td><p>")
            Next

            myBuilder.Append("</tr><p>")

            'Add the data rows.
            For Each myRow As DataRow In myTable.Rows
                myBuilder.Append("<br /><tr align='left' valign='top'>")
                For Each myColumn As DataColumn In myTable.Columns
                    myBuilder.Append("<br /><td align='left' valign='top' style='border: solid 1px blue;'>")
                    myBuilder.Append(myRow(myColumn.ColumnName).ToString())
                    myBuilder.Append("</td><p>")
                Next
            Next
            myBuilder.Append("</tr><p>")
        End If

        'Close tags. 
        myBuilder.Append("</table><p>")
        myBuilder.Append("</body>")
        myBuilder.Append("</html>")

        'Get the string for return. myHtmlFile = myBuilder.ToString();
        Dim myHtmlFile As String = myBuilder.ToString()

        Return myHtmlFile
    End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters here, but you don't want or need linebreaks between rows or cells

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It made a big difference. Now I only have about 10 lines of empty page at the top.

Comment: Did you think to perhaps look at the output of the `StringBuilder` directly or show us what that is? Telling us that you have an issue with some data but not showing us that data seems to be rather counter-intuitive, don't you think? Regardless, what are all those `<p>` and `<br />` tags doing in there? Why would you have paragraphs and line breaks between rows and cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample HTML table (from [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)):

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you study the "permitted content" within the various table elements (also dive deeper, for instance [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary)), there cannot be a `<br>` or `<p>` between `<table>`, `<tr>` or `<td>` elements, only table-related elements are allowed.

A `<tr>` is already a row in the table, so you don't need breaks or paragraphs to move it to a separate row.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I find using XElement to build Html pages easier than using strings.

```
    Dim myHtml As XElement
    'XML literals
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xml-literals
    'note lang and xmlns missing.  see below

    myHtml = <html>
                 <head>
                     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                     <title>Put title here</title>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                     <table border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;">
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th colspan="4">The table header</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                 </body>
             </html>

    'test. five rows, four columns
    For r As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim tr As XElement = <tr align="left" valign="top"></tr>
        For c As Integer = 1 To 4
            Dim td As XElement

            ' XML embedded expressions
            ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xml-literals#use-embedded-expressions-to-create-content
            td = <td align="left" valign="top"><%= "Row:" & r.ToString & "  Col:" & c.ToString %></td>

            tr.Add(td)
        Next
        myHtml.<body>.<table>.<tbody>.LastOrDefault.Add(tr)
    Next

    Dim s As String = myHtml.ToString
    'add lang and xmlns to string!!
    s = s.Replace("<html>", "<html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>")
```

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @Marco - there are links in the code that might prove useful.